# Start rsyslog as unprivileged user

Tags: linux, rsyslog

On Debian, rsyslog runs by default as root (due to POSIX compatibility). It can drop privileges after start, but a cleaner way would be to start as a non-privileged user. What would be a clean way to set up rsyslog to run as non-privileged user? (which user?). While googling, I found start-stop-daemon, which apparently can make daemon start as non-root. is this the way to do it, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 10):

Starting with 4.1.1, `rsyslogd` provides the ability to drop privileges by impersonating as another user and/or group after startup.

Please note that due to `POSIX` standards, `rsyslogd` always needs to start up as root if there is a listener who must bind to a network port below `1024`. For example, the UDP listener usually needs to listen to `514` and as such `rsyslogd` needs to start up as root.

If you do not need this functionality, you can start `rsyslog` directly as an ordinary user. That is probably the safest way of operations. However, if a startup as root is required, you can use the `$PrivDropToGroup` and `$PrivDropToUser` config directives to specify a group and/or user that `rsyslogd` should drop to after initialization. Once this happend, the daemon runs without high privileges (depending, of course, on the permissions of the user account you specified).

All this is from the [rsyslog wiki](http://wiki.rsyslog.com/index.php/Main_Page), which is no longer available, but still on [the archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20180504055432/http://wiki.rsyslog.com/index.php/Main_Page)

You should read it.

Comment: This would be the _cleanest_ way to do it.

Comment: Your cut-and-paste answer actually does not relate to my question. I know how to make rsyslog drop privileges *after* it has been started as root. My question was how to start it as non-root from the beginning. Also, which user should I use. Note: I don't need any port < 1024. Please next time read the whole question, and not just the title. I am new to this forum, but I know how to read the documentation. So please do not insult me.

Comment: @user1968963 if you want people to give you a different answer, you have to provide enough information for people to properly assess your situation.

Comment: @Patrick The question seemed pretty clear; "It can drop privileges after start, but a cleaner way would be to start as a non-privileged user. Could somebody please advise, what would be a clean way to set up rsyslog to run as non-privileged user?". This answer says it's possible, but doesn't explain how to do it

Comment: @user1968963 and MichaelMrozek, __you can use the $PrivDropToGroup and $PrivDropToUser variables located in the config__ . It should be started at boot, and with the variables set in the config file as stated in the wiki, and the manual, and in the answer above that I got from the wiki and the manual. That's the cleanest way. There's no reason you should be running it as a non-root since it runs in place of the stock syslogd.

Comment: @cinelli ...the rest of that sentence is "to specify a group and/or user that rsyslogd should drop to after initialization". That's for dropping privileges, the method he specifically said multiple times he doesn't want. He wants to know how to change the daemon so it starts as an ordinary user from the beginning. It doesn't matter if you think it's useless, that's what he's looking for

Comment: @MichaelMrozek, I understand the question fine. Also, I never stated that I thought it was useless. What I'm trying to say is that the right approach is to use the permission drop features of rsyslog to make it itself run as non-root. It will run as root only to open in order to open critical things (like the UDP ports) and then drops privileges (in a way that never can be undone without a full restart)

Comment: @cinelli It feels like we're going in circles; I don't know which one of us is missing something here. The OP said that he knows it's possible to drop privileges, but would prefer that rsyslog just start as an ordinary user from the beginning. You've said like four times now that the best way is to have it start as root and drop privileges. That's *not what he wants*; it's literally the one thing he said in the question he does not want. Everyone understands that dropping privileges is an option, but he wants a way to start as a normal user, so any answer that involves "run as root" is wrong

Comment: here is the original article, which stimulated my question: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/droppriv.htm

"due to POSIX standards, rsyslogd needs to start up as root if there is a listener who must bind to a network port below 1024 (UDP 514). If you do not need this functionality, you can start rsyslog directly as an ordinary user. That is probably the safest way of operations."

Comment: For container use cases (Docker/Kubernetes), the "run as root and drop privileges"   still requires the container itself to run as root.   It's better if you can just run all the processes as non-root in the 1st place.   I think this answer points the way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found this question while trying to run rsyslog as an unprivileged user to receive remote syslog data from a development-machine.  Assuming others have a similar use-case here is what I found:

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04.

A number of typical rsyslog feature require root, but not all.  If such capabilities are required usually rsyslog will complain inside its own logs.

Examples are:

- `imuxsock` - local syslog logging (can't open /dev/log) - you could work around this with permissiosn - I didn't need it
- `imklog` - kernel logging - obviously needs root
- `$FileOwner` - ie chmod - obviously needs root
- `$ProveDropToUser/Group`
- Access to the console, broadcast messages - eg xconsole etc,...

Apart from that the networking modules work fine as long as they use non-priveleged ports.  Additionally the logging/spooling directories must be accessible.  Noteworthy is that rsyslog.conf seems to use absolute paths.

rsyslog.conf is below - I would further tweak it for per-host logging, but that's beyond the scope:

```
#################
#### MODULES ####
#################

$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# NOTE - listen on  unprivileged port 2514

# provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 2514

# provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 2514

###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# Filter duplicated messages
$RepeatedMsgReduction on

#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022

# These may require root
#$FileOwner syslog
#$FileGroup adm
#$PrivDropToUser syslog
#$PrivDropToGroup syslog

#
# Where to place spool and state files
#
$WorkDirectory /home/user/rsyslog/spool

#
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
#
#$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

#  Default rules for rsyslog.
#
#           For more information see rsyslog.conf(5) and /etc/rsyslog.conf

#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
auth,authpriv.*         /home/user/rsyslog/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/home/user/rsyslog/log/syslog
cron.*              /home/user/rsyslog/log/cron.log
daemon.*            -/home/user/rsyslog/log/daemon.log
kern.*              -/home/user/rsyslog/log/kern.log
user.*              -/home/user/rsyslog/log/user.log

#
# Some "catch-all" log files.
#
*.=debug;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    news.none;mail.none -/home/user/rsyslog/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    cron,daemon.none;\
    mail,news.none      -/home/user/rsyslog/log/messages
```

Starting the daemon only requires a pointing it at your custom config, and specifying a different pid file to keep it separate from the system rsyslog (and ensure you have write access)

```
$ rsyslogd -f rsyslog.conf -i ~/rsyslog/pid
```

Confirm its running:

```
$ ps ux
user     24374  0.0  0.0 347632  1520 ?        Ssl  10:18   0:00 rsyslogd -f rsyslog.conf -i /home/user/rsyslog/pid
$ tail ~/rsyslog/log/syslog
May 19 10:44:18 plutonium rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="26504" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```

Answer (score 1):

On my system (Debian), rsyslog is started by /etc/init.d/rsyslog, which contains something like this:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS
```

according to start-stop-daemon manual, I can specify the "--chuid" option, which will make the process start as another user.

```
start-stop-daemon --start --chuid daemon --user daemon --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS
```

so, the only question remaining is, what would be a good practice. Which user should I use? This user will have write access to my /var/log/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [capabilities](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) to elevate specific privileges of an executable

```
setcap 'cap_dac_override,cap_chown,cap_syslog+epi' /usr/sbin/rsyslogd
```

That way it can run with the needed capabilities as a normal user. You will need to have admin privileges to assign these privileges to the executable.

UPDATE: doesn't work if the application doesn't request the capability before opening the port.

Comment: after `setcap`, and launch rsyslogd , get 
`bash: /usr/sbin/rsyslogd: Operation not permitted`

Comment: @bzhu that seems like a permission issue of your system, not rsyslogd. Nevertheless this approach probably won't work for rsyslogd anyway.

Comment: Yes. it works. as I run the command in a comtainer. the container should have `doker-flags` like `  "--cap-add setfcap"`. after set it it works. thanks @Alex